Big query, GA4 data export
I want to do section "Peaople saw also this items" on my web page - online shop. I have data from GA4 stored in BigQuery.
I thought about extraxting users with info about view_items that they saw in last month. But I cant get it right, cant find this data. Do you know how to extract it? Or maybe it is a better way to do it?
